# Functions to run after previous function is fully executed

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to react and I am stuck in this. I am calling functions in a function like so:

```
submit = () => {
    this.props.getValue();
    this.props.resetValidation();
    this.notify();
    this.props.toggle();
    this.props.disable();
    this.props.actionCost();

    //this.props.action();
    // this.props.actionTable();
  };
```

What is happening is that all the functions are running simultaneously without a function getting fully executed. Why is this happening shouldnt a function be called only after first function runs successfully?

Also how do I run the functions one after the other after a function is fully executed?

Please help

Comment: What do any of those functions do? Sure, this is completely synchronous code. They are executed sequentially, in the order they are coded. Do you need to asynchronously process the callbacks? We need more context. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There are three ways to handle asynchronous operations, **callback function**, **promise** and **async / await**

Comment: Drew reese. These are synchronous functions they should ideally be executed in order they are coded right?

Comment: They are executed in the order they are coded. That doesn't mean they stop and wait for additional functions placed on a callstack, or event queue in JS, to complete. If you need to wait for a function to complete then convert the above function to be `async` and `await` any specific function calls. Do any of these functions *rely* on any previous function having completed? Your question/issue is rather vague and unspecific.

Comment: can you provide an example code

Answer (score 1):

The only way to stop the execution flow, is by using `async/await` or a `generoator` function, and even these are only "syntactic sugar" on top of `Promise`.

You are probably calling an asynchronous function, and expecting it to "complete" without using `await`.

Another situation is calling a function that internally using asynchronous calls (Like `axios` or `fetch`), and reply back with callbacks. In this situation the execution continues, and the callback will be called later, that's way we call them "callback"

For example:

```
console.log('before');
setTimeout(() => console.log('timer completed'), 1000);
console.log('after');
```

Will result in:

```
before
after
timer completed
```

In this example I'm logging `before`, then setting a timeout where I'm providing a callback (a simple function) that will be executed later (1 sec.), meanwhile the execution flow continues, and logs `after`. once the timer reached the system will execute my callback.

In case that you want to execute the `after` after the `timer completed`, you will have to provide a callback that will be called after the execution is done.

like this:

```
function logTimer(doAfter) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timer completed');
    doAfter();
   }, 1000);
}

console.log('before');
logTimer(() => console.log('after'));
```

Comment: Hi gilamran I am not using async any where However in getValue(). I am fetching data through axios

Comment: exactly, fetching data is an asynchronous. I expanded my answer

Comment: Thanks So How do I handle it can you give an example I want to call the asynchronous function first and then execute the other functions?

Comment: expanded the answer